# Is Berkeley DB XML a viable database backend?

Tags: database, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-xml

Apparently, BDB-XML has been around since at least 2003 but I only recently stumbled upon it on Oracle's website: [Berkeley DB XML](http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/xml/index.html). Here's the blurb:

> Oracle Berkeley DB XML is an open source, embeddable XML database with XQuery-based access to documents stored in containers and indexed based on their content. Oracle Berkeley DB XML is built on top of Oracle Berkeley DB and inherits its rich features and attributes. Like Oracle Berkeley DB, it runs in process with the application with no need for human administration. Oracle Berkeley DB XML adds a document parser, XML indexer and XQuery engine on top of Oracle Berkeley DB to enable the fastest, most efficient retrieval of data.

To me it seems that the underlying ideas are technically sound and probably more mature than the newer document-based DBs like CouchDB or MongoDB. It has support for C, C++, Ruby and Perl, as far as I can determine. It even has HA-capabilities like automatic replication using a master/slave model with automatic election.

However, I can't seem to find any projects that use it. Is there something fundamentally wrong with it? Is the license too onerous? Is it too complicated?

Why is it not being used?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I used to be the product manager for Berkeley DB products at Oracle.  I've been around working on these BDB databases for over eight years now, I wrote the "blurb" you copied into your question.

Commercially we're used in (non-exhaustive list, just off the top of my head):

- Autodesk uses BDB XML in Mapquest
- Farelogix uses BDB XML for a reservation system
- Starwood Hotels uses BDB XML to manage information about properties they manage
- Juniper Networks uses BDB XML in the NetScreen security manager
- many I can't name due to contract restrictions...
- and so on...

Berkeley DB XML has been relatively ignored in the open source world, I have no idea why.  There are a few projects here and there have used it, nothing all that public that I know of.  I did recently see [a nifty blog post](http://donnieknows.com/blog/hacking-xquery-emacs-berkeley-db-xml) about how to use BDB XML from within Emacs.  Once setup you can run XQuery statements over XML interactively within the text editor.  That said, it's very viable for commercial and open source use.

XQilla is a project created by the BDB XML engineers from a few other XML projects we knitted together over the years.  We open sourced (Apache 2.0 license) XQilla because it's a great XQuery and XML parsing library.  We're a database company, so the piece that takes XML after it's been parsed and organizes it into our btree databases as well as the work on query optimization, indexing, statistics, and a whole ton of other code is what sits under XQilla but above BDB's btree gluing the two together into BDB XML.  Feel free to use it if it solves your problem, there's no database there at all.

Product built from the ground up for XML generally have a few transactional data structures at their core which manage information on disk.  There's not much optimization that can be done that we've not already done in Berkeley DB and used in Berkeley DB XML.  To say that a database built from the ground up to manage XML is going to be significantly better than BDB XML is saying that there's something missing from Berkeley DB, I don't think there a defensible argument here but I'm willing to learn if someone has information on a concurrent, transactional data structure critical for efficient XML storage that BDB doesn't already implement.

eXist is a Java XML database, we have a Java JNI API if you'd like and we generally beat the pants off eXist in performance, stability and scalability tests.

Sedna is a good XML database, it's Apache 2.0 so it's not a dual-license, it's just FLOSS software.  I'd suggest you benchmark it against BDB XML, you might be surprised.

MarkLogic is a great XML/XQuery database server, they've built a very solid product.  It's not a software library, it's a server.  There are significant differences between BDB XML and MarkLogic, but they are both commercially available - only BDB XML is open source.

Someone mentioned Elliot Rusty Harold's blog on the state of XML databases, be careful it's circa 2007 - hey, isn't that before any NoSQL database existed?  ;-)

Take a look at Kimbro Staken's [old but still relevant review](http://xml.sys-con.com/node/90126) ([turned into a whitepaper by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/pdf/embedded-xml-database-for-xml-data.pdf)), it's good but also dated.  "Use a Native XML Database for Your XML Data: Deciding when an XQuery-based native XML database is better than an SQL database"

The real authority over the years has been [Ron Bourrett](http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/ProdsNative.htm).  He has a lot to say on the subject.

MongoDB and CouchDB are in a different market segment.  They do distributed, partitioned, eventually consistent BASE-style (non ACID) data management and some think they do that very well.  I think they are young, the jury is still out.  They are off to a good start and I hope that they continue to grow, data storage is a hard thing to get right and one size doesn't fit everyone's problem/needs.  BDB XML's distributed story is built on single-master, multi-replica always consistent (if you'd like) log-based replication and PAXOS-based election algorithms when the master fails.  We don't partition data, every node contains the same data (the entire database).  We don't allow writes everywhere, only at the master.  We support more than TCP/IP for replication (heck, you could use a hardware bus custom to your server if you want).  We built our HA product to solve read-scalability, system availability and fault-tolerance.  NoSQL's distributed systems are designed for write anywhere partitioned data management.  Choice is good, right?  :)

XML as a data schema and XQuery as a language to access and manage XML content has been and continues to be a very successful solution.  Maybe not so much in the more public websites using NoSQL solutions these days (which is fine, and interesting to me) but more so in document management, finance, genomics, bioinformatic, data exchange, messaging, and much more.  XML may be a niche database when compared to SQL/relational products but it is certainly much more successful than object databases or any new kid on the block NoSQL database solution.  Every storage solution has its place, XML will continue to do useful things far into the future.

At the end of the day, I hope you pick a database suits your needs.

Comment: If you intend to use it with PHP you may hit some rocks. You have to create PHP extension for it like this: http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showpost.php?s=db5d7d6029545c6aa3752b0d62b8172b&p=10721005&postcount=2

But to compile it you have to manually alter sources as described here:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=3947487#3947487
and also apply a patch linked here:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9120312#9120312

Maybe all this crazy might have something to do with Berkley DB XML unpopularity.

Comment: I've tried to use dbxml at various times ever since it was released, and my beef with is that it's always been a pain to build on Linux. Developers never bothered to package it for *any* popular distro; worse, stock sources would often not compile on Linux without a long list of very inflexible prerequisites and constant tweaking here and there. This is still the case -- the custom build script is buggy on argument parsing, and sources include bugs fixed in debian a year ago.

Comment: Giacomo I think BDB XML suffers from lack of attention within Oracle, it seems to be stagnant.

Comment: I agree with above comments.
I have tried Berckeley DB some years ago and was seduced by its simplicity, flexibility and speed.

But I had to compile it myself and wouldn't go to a solution that was not well packaged and distributed.

Nowadays, you need a PPA and deb packages to be popular.

Plus, I really don't like the Oracle brand at all : Their products, their philosophy, their logo (seriously, red-blood ?. What's wrong with them ?).

And finally, the Licence won't help for its success.
I am sad it is a dead project now. Was it the purpose of Oracle ? Well done guys !

Comment: *Berkeley DB XML has been relatively ignored in the open source world, why I have no idea*  Seems likely to me that the GNU Affero GPL would drive many away from using it in a commercial setting.  I know it's a deal-breaker for my employer.

Comment: I used to work at Sun before they were bought by Oracle and over the years I've used BerkeleyDB, both the non-XML and XML versions, both with and without transactions, and I've always found it to work exactly as advertised, without a fuss, reliable, fast, boring. Exactly what I want in a database.

Answer (score 7):

One thing to keep in mind is Berkeley DB's license. Unless you are going to open source your project, you'll need to buy a license from Oracle, which is why I suspect you don't see more of it. All of the Berkeley DB databases are quite excellent otherwise. I tend to use them for anything I'm not going to distribute (in house projects).

Comment: Just one minor correction: "if you are giong to open source..." should be "if you are NOT going to open source..."

Answer (score 4):

From my experiences Berkeley DB XML has a lot of promise and a lot of relevant use cases. But you should be careful not to expect it to work in all cases. Note that the last release was Berkeley DB XML 2.5.16 in December 22, 2009.

The technology it is based on, Berkeley DB, is very robust and blindingly fast, if you configure it correctly for your use-case. There are many details to get right (e.g. enable transactions, logging, understanding all flags needed to get MVCC working). I believe the majority of people have issues because of this complexity.

I have run into a few other shortcomings though. The biggest one is that the query planner will not use indexes when sorting. This means that you cannot do a pretty common data access pattern which is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 100;
```

If you do this Berkeley DB will check all values of time on disk before ordering, which makes it slow when you go beyond a few tens of thousands of nodes. Someone else reported this as well here:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9754987#9754987

You can enumerate any indexes directly as well, but then you lose the ability to do ad-hoc queries.

Also reported on the forums is some strange behavior related to index types and performance:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9753022#9753022

So, while key based access is fast and reliable, be careful of its immature query planner.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what your needs are. I won't recommend one native xml DB over another, but I can tell you that the publishing industry is an example of an entire sector that has pretty much abandoned relational databases and moved big time to native xml databases for handling the content of their publications. The most prominent(and most expensive) is the one from MarkLogic. eXistDB is an opensource one that seems to be getting some traction.

Here is an excellent article on this subject by one of the preeminent xml gurus, Elliot Rusty Harold.
http://cafe.elharo.com/xml/the-state-of-native-xml-databases/

Comment: Good link! It seems to indicate that some of the unpopularity of BDB-XML is due to the fact that it's not a network server but an embedded database...

Comment: If Berkeley DB were to add a server feature with a HTTP/REST API would that put it into the lead for open source native XML databases?  What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

The best[*] XML repositories are the ones built from the ground up to support XML, like [MarkLogic](http://www.marklogic.com/) or [eXist](http://exist.sourceforge.net/).

However, the storage engine for BDB-XML is the venerable Berkeley DB engine, one of the most wide-spread embedded database engines. It is small, quick and stable.

[BDB-XML](http://oss.oracle.com/xqilla-xquery.html) itself is certainly a capable product. It was formerly sold under the name Sleepycat, if that helps you find any references. It's a combination of the BDB storage engine with the *XQilla* XQuery engine.

Also you might find more information searching for [XQilla](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/HomePage). It's a fairly powerful engine, and still open source.

[*] "best" of course, being a subjective term.

Comment: So are you saying that while it's a capable product, other products seem to have the limelight here?

Comment: Not quite. BDB-XML lets you bury the database inside your product; the others are more traditional in management. It's all in how you want to use them.

Comment: Berkeley DB XML is still open source under the Sleepycat License.  The XQilla software was developed by the same engineers as Berkeley DB XML, we open sourced it.  :)  Yes, we run "in-process" but we've heard many requests for a server version and we take such requests seriously when planning future versions of the product.  We're as much a "native XML database" (NXD) as eXist or MarkLogic.  Just peek inside their code (if you can) and you'll find transactional indexed storage nearly identical to the Berkeley DB BTREE.

Answer (score 1):

So in conclusion, these are all reasons why BDB-XML doesn't seem widely used:

- Only allows built-in, local databases (although there are provisions for doing master-slave replication)
- Not free for commercial use
- Many competing products that were built from the ground up to support XML

There doesn't seem to be any reason not to use it, but likewise there's not much to make it stand out from the competition. On top of that, the recent competition has more of a "Ooh, shiny!" appeal and XML databases themselves are still a niche market.

Comment: At the present time: (a) we are only in-process, (b) we are open source and zero-cost as long as your source code is also open source, (c) we build Berkeley DB XML from the ground up to store XML and we built Berkeley DB from the ground up to be the best transactional storage engine for exactly this kind of solution.

Answer (score -1):

I've been for the same lately and came across the [Sedna XML](http://www.sedna.org/index.html) dbms.

Answer (score -7):

"Is there something fundamentally wrong with it?"

Yes. It's XML.

And unfortunately that means that those who invented it did not bother to take a look at the power of already existing concepts and technologies like, say, relational algebra and relational calculus.

Doing better than those is not a trivial task (and that's putting it politely), and everyone who has tried so far has failed.

That ought to tell you something.

Comment: Thats right, you only need one tool to solve all your problem, we call it the Golden Hammer. It pounds nails, pounds screws, cuts wood, welds metal, polishes glass, and plunges toilets. One tool is all you need whatever your domain, whatever problem you need to solve. Only 3 easy payments of $29.99 + shipping and handling, buy your Golden Hammer today!

Comment: I'm not sure I agree here - XML is just a way to store bags of structured information. It's a bit wordy, sure, but it gets the job done and there's lots of support libraries available.

Document-based databases are really becoming popular right now because they can scale better when handled properly and they're simpler to program for. XML is a good candidate for storing documents imho.

Comment: How would you store a HTML document in a relational database to make searches like 'find the longest piece that is inside <i> that is inside a <h2> of class "test"?

Comment: The answer to that will not fit inside a comment.  And what does "of class 'test'" mean in the context of an HTML document ?