# Native XML DataBase - Sedna -

Tags: asp.net, xml, xml-database, sedna

I've heard a lot and read a lot regarding Sedna , native xml database but never saw a life example or a source code or how it could be implemented .

is it right that I can build an ASP.net , C# Website and use totaly XML native DB ?
if its possible , I would Like to know more .

if a live example exist , that would help too.

I would like to try it.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a C# or ASP.Net developer, but I can guarantee you can build an application that uses a Native XML Database, whatever your language is. The "Native XML Database" specifies that internally, the database manager uses the actual XML to store data, and not some other intermediary format, in contrast to XML-Enabled databases.

For further information concerning such differences you can look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database#Native_XML_databases).
I tried to make this clarification so you don't mislead Native XML with XML Embedded database. 
In the link above you can also see some XML Native Databases, and some of them are written in C or C++ (such as Sedna itself, but also Berkeley XML DB, which has a pretty good overview in the question [Is Berkeley DB XML a viable database backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493341/is-berkeley-db-xml-a-viable-database-backend)). Some of these databases can be embedded, but that is heavily dependend on your development language. A database I know that is  embeddable is eXist, which is fully written in Java (and can be embedded in Java apps). You'll have to access the database from your application through network.

Since your preferable language is C# and your intention is to deal with Sedna (I presume), you can download the drivers [here](http://sedna.org/download.html#drivers) (there are C# drivers!).

Please note I have not tested it myself.